# Section headings not vertically aligned on different pages (font dependent)

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vertical-alignment

Consider the following MWE where the first section heading contains letters with ascender and the second does not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-serif-pro or
% https://ctan.org/pkg/sourceserifpro
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}

\begin{document}
\section*{\rlap{\rule{8.5in}{0.04pt}}bbbbb}
\leavevmode\rlap{\rule{8.5in}{0.04pt}}bbbbb

\newpage

\section*{nnnnn\llap{\rule{8.5in}{0.04pt}}}
nnnnn\llap{\rule{8.5in}{0.04pt}}
\end{document}
```

Why are the baselines in the two section headings misaligned? I have tried the following tests:

1. Baselines **do align**: When set in Computer Modern (without `fontspec` and under pdfLaTeX), Latin Modern, TeX Gyre Termes, etc.
2. Baselines **do not align**: When set in some of the commercial fonts I have.
3. Baselines **do align**: With only body text `bbbbb` and `nnnnn` (i.e., commenting out the two `\section*`’s), for all aforementioned fonts, including Source Serif Pro and other commercial fonts.

The third observation really threw me off…

Answer (score 2):

The b in Source Serif Pro is larger than the one in latin modern. And more importantly in a section title its height is larger than \topskip. This means that its baseline will be moved down by 0.45pt at the start of the page. If you want to avoid this effect, enlarge \topskip with such fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\section*{\the\fontcharht\font`\b bbbb}

\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}
\section*{\the\fontcharht\font`\b bbbb}

\the\topskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Enlarging `\topskip` is not a good option for me as it messes up other body-only pages. I decided to `\newcommand*\headingstrut{\vrule height\dimexpr\f@size\p@*880/1000 width\z@\relax}` and put `\headingstrut` wherever I could in the class declaration.